# Discord Bot Python Server Reaction roles and Embeds

Tags: python, discord, bots

Sorry, everyone. I'm new to this, but I wanted to create a private Discord bot for my server. I need it to send embeds and handle reaction roles. I'm trying to find a way, but I'm having trouble. If anyone wants to help me, I would greatly appreciate it!
Last thing i don't know if someone can use my commands even if he's just an @everyone or another role other than Owner, i'm looking to correct even this problem!
If it helps here it is my code:

1. Bot.py

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands


intents = discord.Intents.all()
intents.messages = True
intents.guilds = True
intents.members = True


bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)


@bot.command()
async def supercalifragilistichespiralidoso(ctx):

    embed = discord.Embed(
        title='Calculate or roll stats',
        description='Exist various ways to create Character'
                    '1. Point buy 2. Roll stats',
        color=discord.Color.dark_blue()
    )


    embed.add_field(name='Point buy', value='Sorry this is the text, i\'m writing this to not translate all (i\'m bad)', inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name='Roll stats', value='Sorry this is the text, i\'m writing this to not translate all (i\'m bad)', inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name='', value='Woosh',)

    embed.set_footer(text="Boom"),
    embed.set_author(name="The name of my bot"),

    await ctx.send(embed=embed),

bot.run('Don\'t look at my token pls')
```

2. Main.py

```
import bot

if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.run_discord_bot()
```

Ah, i already said that, i'm searching some help to understand something about creating a Python bot from scratch, I'm trying to search more info as i can and trying to do it myself, but if anyone helps i appreciate that!
Anyway if you want any more information, I'm creating this bot for a D&D 5e guild italian server so he could help me and my friends not to stress everytime about people entering and things